# Make Select Options Be Just Links

Tags: php, jquery, html, select, hyperlink

I've got the follow script that let's a user select a "folder" and then the jquery code listens and displays the code.  Right now the code is in a select box but I'd like them to just display as links instead.  Is this possible?

Here's the jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#theselect").change(function() {
var option = $(this).val();
var selectedUser = $("#thename").val();
$.get("selectfolders.php", {select:option,username:selectedUser},function(data){
    $("#theresult").html(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
});
});
});
</script>
```

Here's the php code to look up and display all the users folders: (This is what I want to be links instead of a select box.)

```
<select name="theselect" id="theselect">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?
$thelistquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM folders WHERE username='$username'");
while ($lrows = mysql_fetch_array($thelistquery)) {
$id = $lrows['ID'];
$foldername = $lrows['foldername'];
$newfoldername = mysql_real_escape_string($foldername);

echo "<option value='$newfoldername'>$newfoldername</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Selectfolders.php

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$theselect = $_GET['select'];

$thelistquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM folders WHERE username='$username'");
while ($lrows = mysql_fetch_array($thelistquery)) {
$id = $lrows['ID'];
$foldername = $lrows['foldername'];
$newfoldername = mysql_real_escape_string($foldername);

if($_GET['select'] == "$newfoldername") {
//What to display
}
}


?>
```

Comment: You want to select an `option`, and then go to that URL? Or you want to turn the `option`s from a `select` element *into* (a list of) links? Can you show your HTML?

Comment: take the options from select and turn them into links.  The html of each option is there already in the second code box.  I'm using php to grab the list of all the users folders and displaying them.

Comment: And you want to do this client-side, or server-side? And that's *not* HTML in the second code box, that's a [tag:php] script that *generates* the [tag:html].

Comment: server side is fine but what ever works best.

Comment: ... so why not just remove `<select>` and replace `echo <option` etc with `echo <a`? do you really need someone to give you that code?

Comment: How does the jquery know to send the data of each option if I do that though.  That's my problem.  I know how to make them look like links, the question is how to get them to work and display the information. The jquery code uses `<select name="theselect" id="theselect">` to know which one is selected and what to send to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Change the jQuery to work on the  tags click event rather than a  change event.
Note, the ".folders" selector which is the class I added to the  tags so you don't need to use a selector that references all  tags on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".folders").click(function() {    //<-------Changes here
 var option = $(this).val();
 var selectedUser = $("#thename").val();
 $.get("selectfolders.php", {select:option,username:selectedUser},function(data){
  $("#theresult").html(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

Modified the output to display links by removing the surrounding  tag and changing the  tag to an  tag.  Also added a class to easily select it with jQuery.

```
$thelistquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM folders WHERE username='$username'");
while ($lrows = mysql_fetch_array($thelistquery)) {
 $id = $lrows['ID'];
 $foldername = $lrows['foldername'];
 $newfoldername = mysql_real_escape_string($foldername);

 //Changed the below to a link with a class
 echo "<a class='folders' value='$newfoldername'>$newfoldername</a>";
}
echo "<input type='text' value='$username' name='thename' />";
```

Comment: When I click on them they don't show any information.  It's not passing the folder name i think.

Comment: you'll need to post what's in the selectfolders.php.  Also the </a> is a closing tag and should be there.  Also note, the input for the selectedUser isn't being out by the code posted, I assumed you excluded it.  I added it for completeness.

Comment: I put the code in there for the selectfolders.php  I have a hidden input with the username in there selectedUser field.  It's taken care of.  Thanks for the help, not sure what's going wrong with it.

Comment: It's still not working though.  Idk if I made that clear.  Still nothing comes up.